# JSCodeshift declare new variable

Tags: javascript, jscodeshift

I want to write a template function to create new Variables in JsCodeShift.

Anyone has an Idea how? Or some better documentation?

I tried the code below down, according to [this](https://github.com/benjamn/ast-types/blob/master/def/core.js).

```
 const j = api.jscodeshift;
 let test = j.variableDeclaration('let',
    j.variableDeclarator(
      j.identifier('test'),
      null
    )
  );
```

But I get the error

```
Error: {id: [object Object], init: null, loc: null, type: VariableDeclarator, 
comments: null} does not match field "declarations": [VariableDeclarator | 
Identifier] of type VariableDeclaration
```

Cheers Jens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out why, I forget to put the second parameter in brackets

so this works:

```
const j = api.jscodeshift;
let test = j.variableDeclaration('let',
   [j.variableDeclarator(
     j.identifier('test'),
     null
   )]
 );
```

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/javascript/write-code-to-rewrite-your-code
was the most helpful article